# how to includes and exclude javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using axios interceptor where in i need to write an check

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
         if (!config.url.includes("UserService") &&
            config.url.includes("UserService/action") ||
            config.url.includes("UserService/getter") ||
            config.url.includes("UserService/setter") ||
            config.url.includes("UserService/reader") {
               console.log("Allowed 4 services and excluded all which came with UserService");

            }
            return config;
         }, (error) => {

            return Promise.reject(error);
         });
```

how to set every url should not includes except UserService/action, UserService/getter, UserService/setter, UserService/reader

how to put condition please guide

Thanks

Comment: I'm misunderstanding what you are asking. What shouldn't every URL include?

Comment: what ever includes UserService these should not be excluded except  those UserService/action, UserService/getter, UserService/setter, UserService/reader so may be some url like UserService/someExist this would not consider

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, to start with: the if statement has no right paren. After that, there's the matter of operator precedence: AND binds more tightly than OR, so `!A && B || C` is equivalent to `!(A && B) || C`; this is definitely not what you want, based on your request.

Comment: Please clarify: you want to exclude any URLs that include "UserService", except those 4 exceptions? What must happen to other URLs that do not include "UserService" at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand quite well. But if you want to know if the url includes any of these strings: `UserService/action`, `UserService/getter`, `UserService/setter`, `UserService/reader`

you can use a verification like this:

```
const check = (url: string) => {
    let allow = ["action", "getter", "setter", "reader"]
    return allow.some(x => url.includes(`UserService/${x}`))
}
```